# RSA encryption text/message using our PublicKey - JavaScript or ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encryption, node-rsa

What I have to do is encrypt a small message through a public key. I have the public key but I can't encrypt any messages.
I have tried with JSEncrypt, encrypt-rsa, hybrid-crypto-js, NodeRSA and crypto. Can´t encrypt message.

The key is something like

```
      let keyData = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBCgKCAQEAzK1MF/...-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
```

The closest to getting anything was through 'NodeRSA', which when doing `key.importkey(keyData, 'pkcs8')`, returns an error `"InvalidAsn1Error: encoding too long"`

Can someone give me a hand?

---

My code is:

```
import NodeRSA from 'node-rsa';
const key = new NodeRSA();
let keyData = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBCgKCAQEAzK1MF/...-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
key.importKey(keyData, 'pkcs8');
```

I stopped here because you gave me the mistake.

Comment: The second parameter of `importKey()` must be `'pkcs8-public'` or `'pkcs8-public-pem'` for a PEM encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format or omitted altogether. `'pkcs8'` imports a PEM encoded _private_ key in PKCS#8 format. By the way, `'pkcs8'` is actually a misnomer in the context of a _public_ key, but there is already an issue about that.

Comment: with `'pkcs8-public'` or `'pkcs8-public-pem'` give a error `InvalidAsn1Error: Expected 0x30: got 0x2`

Comment: I tried with `'pkcs1'` and `'public'` and give same errors!

Comment: Which node-rsa version are you using?

Comment: "node-rsa":"^1.1.1"
[library node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, see online: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/GrandFussyProperty

Comment: Works also in my local NodeJS environment.

Comment: with your keys i can use but with my key have error....
I try encrypt online with my key and work...
My key have 2048 bits, have more length that your key..

Comment: Without inspecting your key, I can't say much. Post your key (it is a public key) or a sample key.

Comment: MIIBCgKCAQEAzK1MF/FXZ7OnaUCwAm+/yUfdJ0S40nntsJRsYXo5wZFSgiPm9Wlo\noUFmBM6C518ailenaVPJo78SSwepBiGtNwf95jCU2+2PAR2uf5ZH5fSbkKZS84O5\nKelskf+AQoeT555iSZTFWouC+tmMRcrtJHBhRh4nJ0iPnNQLv9q3s0NdMKqOcpCM\nbaDQIxfXZI9kcx4k8TvT/4NxBOrRTDFs9aojJZaVMb4iSbN2GHY1i3rPYo1JX0rt\nUS+eH/OSe1+HJQ6ybR98rqWdIRIMGgosYPYivbds8FkF60vyWvpEs2v0+qqgF+st\n/gGk7+eh0OzAsKFfb6kL7rAF5AtDvsX6OQIDAQAB

Comment: This is _not_ an X.509/SPKI key, but a public key in PKCS#1 format. I.e. first, you must use `'pkcs1-public'` or `'pkcs1-public-pem'` as 2nd parameter of `importKey()`, or omit the 2nd parameter altogether, and second header and footer are wrong and must be: `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`. S. also online: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/UnhappyColdShockwave

Comment: Thanks, this works for me!
I have other problems, but I think is the API...
Thanks for all!